# SQLAlchemy inserts the previous default value into the next one

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a column with a default value of uuid4 in the declarative_base class. The previous UUID value stays the next one when I run the script file. How can I provide take a new UUID each time on the default value?

```py
import os
import uuid
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base


Base = declarative_base()

class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = "test"
    id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    msg = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    uuid = Column(String(32), default=uuid.uuid4().hex, nullable=True)


engine = create_engine(
    os.getenv('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'),
    echo=True
)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

for x in range(2):
    model = Test(msg=f"Hey! - {x}")
    with Session() as session:
        session.add(model)
        session.commit()
        session.close()
```

**Echo Output**

```
2022-10-10 14:42:44,963 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS VARCHAR)
2022-10-10 14:42:44,963 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2022-10-10 14:42:45,005 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT schema_name()
2022-10-10 14:42:45,005 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00022s] ()
2022-10-10 14:42:45,081 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT CAST('test max support' AS NVARCHAR(max))
2022-10-10 14:42:45,081 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00032s] ()
2022-10-10 14:42:45,202 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2022-10-10 14:42:45,204 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO test (msg, uuid) OUTPUT inserted.id VALUES (?, ?)
2022-10-10 14:42:45,204 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00020s] ('Hey! - 0', '58a2f6d418a9428b92c0b81ad81c4585')
2022-10-10 14:42:45,311 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2022-10-10 14:42:45,371 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2022-10-10 14:42:45,371 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO test (msg, uuid) OUTPUT inserted.id VALUES (?, ?)
2022-10-10 14:42:45,371 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 0.1675s ago] ('Hey! - 1', '58a2f6d418a9428b92c0b81ad81c4585')
2022-10-10 14:42:45,478 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
```

**What I Expected Output**

```
2022-10-10 14:56:18,458 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS VARCHAR)
2022-10-10 14:56:18,458 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2022-10-10 14:56:18,518 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT schema_name()
2022-10-10 14:56:18,519 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00022s] ()
2022-10-10 14:56:18,599 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT CAST('test max support' AS NVARCHAR(max))
2022-10-10 14:56:18,599 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00018s] ()
2022-10-10 14:56:18,704 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2022-10-10 14:56:18,706 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO test (msg, uuid) OUTPUT inserted.id VALUES (?, ?)
2022-10-10 14:56:18,706 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00019s] ('Hey! - 0', '58a2f6d418a9428b92c0b81ad81c4585')
2022-10-10 14:56:18,846 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2022-10-10 14:56:18,862 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2022-10-10 14:56:18,862 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO test (msg, uuid) OUTPUT inserted.id VALUES (?, ?)
2022-10-10 14:56:18,863 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 0.1569s ago] ('Hey! - 1', '13f37ce5a48c44bbaa0c883f2f35da3d')
2022-10-10 14:56:18,929 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see the difference between the actual and the expected.

Comment: Hi @SergioLema, there is a duplicate UUID field however, I'm expecting a different UUID for each insert. Actual 2 rows inserted starts with 58a... UUID. Expected starts with 58a... and 13f.... UUID's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When SQLAlchemy sets up an ORM class it looks at the column `default=` entries. If they are a scalar value or a function call that returns a scalar value then they are evaluated once and that value is used for each new instance of the class. However, if the `default=` is a *callable* then it is called for each new instance.

In your case, `uuid.uuid4().hex` returns a scalar (str) value so it is only being evaluated once and the same value is used for each instance. Depending on the DBAPI layer you might be able to use

```py
    uuid = Column(String(32), default=uuid.uuid4, nullable=True)
```

note `uuid.uuid4`, not `uuid.uuid4()` — but since your column is `String` that may not work. (At least it didn't work for me with `sqlite://`.)

Another way to "convert" the `default=` into a callable is to use a lambda:

```py
    uuid = Column(String(32), default=lambda: uuid.uuid4().hex, nullable=True)
```

My test with `sqlite://` produces the effect that you desire.